# Create treeview of document library in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I need to display the files of a document library as a treeview. I've searched around online at various sites and most don't help me out at all. I found a great website for creating a document treeview in SharePoint Designer, at this address: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1073&page=2.

I'm stuck and hope someone can take a look and help me out. I'm at "Save the file in the SharePoint Designer and then check the document library where the code is being stored in SharePoint" about 4/5 of the way down page 2. The resulting treeview on my SharePoint site shows the parent and child nodes, and when I click on a child node I get a "This page cannot be displayed" screen.

What is the purpose in the directions of creating the link in the child node? What step connects the files in my document library with the treeview so they display? Any ideas?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The article you mention will never get you a dynamic tree view! Its purpose is to design a static (i.e. hard-coded) menu, with defined nodes and target URLs... If you get a 404 error when testing your tree view, it probably means you entered a broken link at the previous step...

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. So the child nodes are just the hard coded files etc., right? What is the purpose of the link in those instructions? I'm not sure what it's supposed to link too?

Comment: Yup, child nodes are just hard-coded links. The links you enter in the `NavigateUrl` property is the target link for each node.